# Can we deploy .net 4.0 application on window server 2003 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net-4.0

We have existing server with following configuration:

**Hardware** : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5430 @ 2.66 GHz 2.67 GHz, 8.00 GB of RAM

**Installed Software**: MS Windows Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition Service Pack 2

**IIS** : IIS V6.0

**MS .net Framework** : 3.5

Can we upgrate this configuration for .net 4.0?

Comment: Yes. Have you even tried it? See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982671

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on SP2, then yes.

This has been asked before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347722/can-i-run-net-4-0-web-applications-on-windows-server-2003

It points to an article here:
http://johan.driessen.se/posts/getting-an-asp.net-4-application-to-work-on-iis6

Also the Microsoft page for the .net 4 framework installer http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17718 shows the requirements to be:

> Supported Operating System
>
> Windows 7, Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack
> 2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2
> SP1, Windows Vista Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 3  •Windows
> XP SP3 •Windows Server 2003 SP2 •Windows Vista SP1 or later •Windows
> Server 2008 (not supported on Server Core Role) •Windows 7 •Windows
> Server 2008 R2 (not supported on Server Core Role) •Windows 7 SP1
> •Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 •
>
> Supported Architectures:
>
> •x86 •x64 •ia64
> (some features are not supported on ia64 for example, WPF)
>
> Hardware Requirements:
>
> •Recommended Minimum: Pentium 1 GHz or higher with 512
> MB RAM or more •Minimum disk space: •x86 – 850 MB •x64 – 2 GB
> •
>
> Prerequisites:
>
> •Windows Installer 3.1 or later •Internet Explorer
> 5.01 or later

Answer (score 1):

If you download .NET 4.0, you will be able to deploy applications with this framework.

However, there are additional steps to get it working. Once you install .NET 4.0, run the following from your `C:\windows\system32` folder:

`cscript iisext.vbs /EnFile C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll`

Note that the actual version number *may* vary based on the current version number of .NET. Then, run `cscript iisext.vbs /ListFile` and you should see a "1" next to the .dll file for 4.0.

Good luck!

Reference: http://johan.driessen.se/posts/getting-an-asp.net-4-application-to-work-on-iis6